# Javascript Image Gallery with Image Manipulation

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, image-gallery

Can anyone please suggest a good javascript image gallery library that comes with image manipulation features, such as cropping, rotating, and zooming?

I've searched high and low and only found one or the either but not both combined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

StudioJS is a rapidly growing collection of jQuery plugins for image cropping, resizing, and editing.

https://github.com/nathanaeljones/studiojs

Comment: But does it have gallery functionality like Galleria?

Comment: Probably not, you'll have to add one on your own

Comment: Ok, is there an easy way to combine them?

Comment: Probably not - what o would have done would be to take an existing gallery and try to pass the selected image to the editor. Then i'd probably need to save the image on the server and pass it back to the gallery. Start with that and use stackoverflow to ask your various questions.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
  $('#target').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
  });  
})
```

https://github.com/lingqingmeng/simple-shopify-gallery/